# Phonegap: how to hide notification bar permanently

Tags: android, cordova, swipe, android-notification-bar

I'm developing an Android app using Phonegap. I'm running it in fullscreen mode (menu/notification bars are hidden) but when I swipe down near the top of the screen notification bar slides down - how can I prevent it?

Comment: Note that you cannot prevent it as of Android 4.4, as I understand it. The user always has the right to access the notification and navigation bars. Full-screen mode is for showing more content with fewer distractions, not for taking control of the device away from the user.

Comment: yeah, but I wanted to enable this gesture to show another in-app menu - instead it is showing almost every time my in-app menu WITH notificatin bar on top of it :/ (app will be running only in landscape mode so swiping form the very top of the screen is almost inevitable)